# How to press Upload button through VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I was searching a lot on the web and found your website very helpfull - that is why I have not posted anything yet, just reading.
However, I need your advice in the following step of my project. The porject is to automate the creation/placing of ad for selling goods.
The website is http://olx.bg/adding/
What I am failing to do through VBA is to press the blue square called "ДОБАВИ СНИМКА" which stands for "ADD PHOTO" in the form.
Once pressed a default BROWSE window opens to select the file.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add two references to your VBA project:

1. Microsoft Internet Controls
2. Microsoft HTML Object Library

---

The HTML behind the button has an id = add-files which makes it pretty easy to locate using `getElementById`

Here is a working example:

```
Sub PushAddPhotoButton()
    Dim IEexp As InternetExplorer
    Set IEexp = New InternetExplorer
    IEexp.Visible = True
    IEexp.navigate "http://olx.bg/adding/"

    Do While IEexp.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

    Dim photoButton As HTMLInputElement
    Set photoButton = IEexp.Document.getElementById("add-files")

    If (Not photoButton Is Nothing) Then
        photoButton.Click
    Else
        MsgBox "Button not found on web page."
    End If

    IEexp.Quit
    Set IEexp = Nothing
End Sub
```

---

If your IE security settings are on 'High' for Internet then you won't get a dialog or an error.  The IE window will simply flash and then be gone.

Change to:

[image]

Comment: Portland Runner Thank you for your time and help! I tested it (IE8, VBA 7.1) but no default BROWSE window opens once I pass the photoButton.Click step.

Comment: If you step through the code (F8) will it work?  If you don't see the message box then it's found the button and clicked it.  I'm wondering if you have any 3rd party plug-ins such as language translators that take focus away from the click or delay it enough that it doesn't run.  If so you may need to 'wait' a second or two before the click.  FWIW, works fine on my machine.

Comment: I tested with F8 again, paused (waited) before the step photoButton.Click over 5 sec but still new (Browse) window does not appear. No 3rd party plug-ins on my machine /none that I know of/. I tested on another computer - no luck as well. If it works fine on yours then I start thinking of the configuration of IE but have nothing specific in mind.

Comment: Interesting, I just played around with security and found that if you have it set to 'high' the IE window will just close.  Set it to 'Medium-high' and the open dialog works.  Check your settings and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks Portland Runner! Originally I was on CUSTOM settings. Then I changed them and tried in Medium-high and also in Medium both in Debug (F8) mode and playing the sub direclty but in vain - no dialog window at all. Could it be the Excel/VBA settings?

Comment: GOOD NEWS :) After upgrading from IE8 to IE11 the BROWSE window appeared. I could not find what is the change I need to make in IE8 to make it work. Thanks a lot Portland Runner for your help and support! I will vote up once I collect the minimum of 15 points required :)

Comment: Great, glad you got it sorted out.  And welcome to SO!

Comment: You know, a few days later the mistery is back ... :) You've probably noticed that there are some Dropdown boxes on the webpage - after the migration from IE8 to IE11 the code which was selecting the values (e.g. selectedindex=3) and then Clicking the selected value in order to Show the following Dropdown boxes STOPed working :) If I run IE11 in Compatibility mode this code works, BUT the other part of the code which You helped me out (addPhoto and open Browser) is not working. I am So Close to Give Up Now ...